# What happens when we divide in the conditional probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I've been looking at the conditional probability definition to try to figure out how to think about the scaling that occurs.

$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

We are dividing with number between $0$ and $1$, properly having chance of increasing the size of the numerator i.e if they are dependant. This since we reduce the space of outcomes we consider when we take $B$ as a given and dependant.

Is there a way to think about the magnitude of this increase in a reasonable way?

Comment: Whether $P(A)$ or $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ is bigger depends on the relationship between $A$ and $B$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent [and $P(B)>0$] then $P(A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: The division by $P(B)$ is to normalize and get a probability, i.e. $0 \leq P(A | B) \leq 1$. A typical visualization is to draw a Venn diagram, color in the conditioning event $B$, and then only consider the part of the Venn diagram that is colored in

Comment: by conditioning on the event B, you are eliminating certain outcomes from consideration.

Comment: $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}\ge P(A \cap B)$ is intuitively reasonable: $A$ and $B$ are more likely to happen together if you restrict consideration to cases when $B$ happens

Comment: "So we are dividing with number less then 1 ,properly increasing the size of the numerator.

Is there a way to think about the magnitude of this increase in a reasonable way?" This is weird. I'm not sure what you are getting at. Please clarify the question with more context? It's not clear what you are comparing or what you are asking?

Comment: @AdamRubinson By properly I refer to that we assume $B$ happened and thus need to rescale the events of $A\cap B$

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused Yes, I can see that .. but what I dont get is that we scale the rest of the probabilities with this number. Say that $P(B)=\frac{1}{2}$,then we double all the probabilities within $B$, for instance those in $A$ that are part of $B$ i.e P(A\cap B)

Comment: @user21312 Yes, you scale these up to be relative to the "area" of the event $B$ that you are in. To use your example, if $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, then $P(B | B) = 1 = 2 \times P(B)$, so the scaling makes sense.

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused the probabilities of $B$ are all "reduced"(they are not really reduced, they are $\frac{1}{2}$ in that setting), they are  by $\frac{1}{2}$ relative to the whole space! Now that we take them as given to have occurred we must scale them back to $1$ .. that formulation made it clearer to me at least. You wanna write an answer like this? leave out the part of $P(*\mid B)$ becoming a probability, this is hard for beginners to understand I think. Maybe as an additional comment

Comment: @Henry Generally this is true, that was not the question I have in mind however. Maybe the question is clearer now?

Comment: @user21312  No - I am still uncertain as to whether you are saying "$P(A \mid B) \gt P(A \cap B)$" (always true if $0 < P(B)<1$) or "$P(A \mid B) \gt P(A)$" (sometimes true)?

Comment: @Henry I wanna say they first one.. let me think of how slipped into the second..

Comment: OK - then my earlier comment was "A and B are more likely to happen together if you restrict consideration to cases when B happens"

Comment: @Henry that far I got, it was the actual scaling that I was considering i.e the magnitude, but I think I cracked it. All events that are in $B$  have $P=\frac{1}{2}$ of happening relative to the whole space. If we want to "remove"( or nullify) that, we multiply by $2$

Answer (score 2):

It's correcting for the fact that you already know $B$ occurred.

For example, if you wanted to find the proportion of male dogs that are brown, you would divide the number of dogs that are both male and brown by the number of male dogs.  The proportion of male dogs that are brown is the probability that a randomly selected male dog is brown, or equivalently the probability a randomly selected dog is brown, given it is male.  In terms of your formula, we would say $A$ is the event "The dog is brown" and $B$ is the event "The dog is male," so the proportion of male dogs that are brown is $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$, and the proportion of dogs that are both brown and male is $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$.  Then the first sentence in this paragraph is just saying $$\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful when considering proportions, but when considering arbitrary probabilities it doesn't exactly carry over I think

Comment: @user21312 Why doesn't it carry over?  A probability can usually be thought of as a proportion of times an event occurs.

Comment: Indeed, but isn't that only when there are finitely many outcomes?

Comment: I don't think so?  The formula you wrote is specifically for events $A$ and $B$.  When considering an event $A$, ultimately there are only two possible outcomes: $A$ occurs, or it doesn't.  The events could be things like random variables taking on a specific value or a value within a specific range, even if those random variables can take on infinitely many values.  Unless you mean the generalization of this formula for things like probability density functions?

Comment: Regardless, even it is a good explanation it doesn't really provide an explanation of the  logic of the particular magnuite, not explicitly anyway.